# How to create SQLite FK by FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, sqlite, fluent-migrator

How I can change this code to create FK? This works without any errors and the console indicates that fk is created. But I don't see fk in the generated db...

```
Create.Table("Level")
.WithIdColumn()
.WithColumn("Name").AsFixedLengthString(128).NotNullable();

Create.Table("Team")
.WithIdentityIdColumn()
.WithColumn("Number").AsFixedLengthString(256).NotNullable()
.WithColumn("LevelId").AsInt32().NotNullable().ForeignKey("Level", "Id")
```

It also does not work although the console indicates that fk is created

```
Create.ForeignKey()
.FromTable("Team").ForeignColumn("LevelId")
.ToTable("Level").PrimaryColumn("Id");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reported issue
https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/pull/638.
Waiting for the solution.
Now we need to use workaround with raw sql.

Answer (score 0):

Well if all else fails, you could try to to write the sql command to create the FK and execute the command in your up function using the 'Execute([YOUR COMMAND])' function.

However both the examples that you wrote should work. I would try to reach to the lib creator and check for support.

Comment: See https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/pull/638. As I understand it's already fixed but is not released...